# Django Rest Framework: filtering on relationships using hyperlink URIs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I'm using Django Rest Framework to create a simple API. I have two models with a foreign key relationship:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('Publisher', ...)

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = ...
```

I am serializing them using hyperlink identifiers:

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/1/article/1",
  "publisher": {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/1/publisher/1",
    "name": "Publisher One"
  },
  ...
}
```

I'd like to filter all articles against the publisher of a specific article, ideally something of this form:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/1/article?publisher=http://localhost:8000/api/1/publisher/1
```

I tried creating a custom `FilterClass`, however `url` isn't an actual field on the model, so I'm uncertain how to reference it.

If I extract the `id` from the URL and pass that through it works as expected, but I'd rather the client not need to know how to parse a hyperlinked identifier for the "real" identifier.

I can add the `id` to the serializer as well but if that's the solution what even is the point of the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an alternate approach using `drf`'s `ViewSet` actions. Rather than use the `Publisher` URI to filter the `Article` endpoint, I added a custom action to the publisher view to return the matching articles:

```
class PublisherViewSet(base.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Publisher.objects.order_by('name')
    ...

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=True)
    def unclaimed(self, request, pk=None):
        serializer = ArticleFieldSerializer(context={'request': request})
        unclaimed = models.Article.objects.unfinished().filter(publisher=pk)
        return Response(
            [serializer.to_representation(article) for article in unclaimed]
        )
```

No parsing of the URI is required, I just need to append the action to it and `GET`.

Being able to filter on URI would be a lot more flexible but this works.